# $_POST in php is inconsistent

Tags: php, post

I've started to learn PHP. `$_POST` variable is working in some of files, that I'm even able to post the data obtained through `$_POST` to database.

Strangely, `$_POST` is not working in few files.  I mean its inconsistent.

Below is the html:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST" action="addemail.php">
<label for="firstname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
<label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is the PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php 
    $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];   

    print($first_name);

    $dcf = mysqli_connect('localhost','uname','XXX','elvis_store') 
                 or die('Error connecting to MYSQL Server.');

    $query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email) " .
                    "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dcf, $query);

    mysqli_close($dcf);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers to overcome this issue will be of great help.

Comment: Can you show the source where the `$_POST` didn't work? My best guess would be some typo!

Comment: Maybe you use in these few files `<form method="get">` instead of `post` ?

Comment: that means your are making same mistake again and blaming php

Comment: Either what [above said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945303/post-in-php-is-inconsistent#comment14283466_10945303) or you are using a query string form action.

Comment: $_POST CAN'T be inconsistent, it either works or it doesn't. If it works for some cases and not for others, YOU are doing something wrong.

Comment: you asked it again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909334/post-not-working-in-php

Comment: $_POST works fine, its in your code

Comment: Did you try the advice that Lawrence Cherone gave you in your last answer?

Comment: @Rinzler -  no hard feelings about my repost  and neither i'm blaming php. May be for your expertise it may see a trivial thing but for a beginner in php like me each and evey small clue will be a great thing. So plz dont come out with comments that may discourage a learner  and ones strong belief that he can get a lead here.  Sorry if my comment hurt you.

Comment: @Kenny Cason - Yes, i did all the things as per his advise and i'm nor running wamp

Comment: "And more importantly plz don't give negative rating to this question as the chances of getting a proper answer turns out to be hard" I don't always downvote "newbies", but when I do I make sure the question deserves it and still does. Your question did sorry. 1) You failed to post any code. 2) You haven't even told us what is (according to you) inconsistent.

Comment: @Dobiatowski - verified the method is post.

Comment: being a newbie doesnt excuse yourself i am going through the same process "but you need to learn from your mistakes" and follow so rules and your question should be clear and concise showing research and effort . they are so many examples you can find on $_post. follow them will help you .

Comment: Any errors? Why do you say it doesn't work? What is your expected outcome, but what actually happened?

Comment: @Rinzler I'm willing to bet it's not a code issue but a usage issue. i.e. trying to directly open the file, and not running it through Apache or something trivial like that. I've tutored programming for years and have seen that happen many times haha They install W/L/Mamp and then don't use it :)

Comment: yes that could be anything ;)

Answer (score 1):

$_POST should not have any consistency issues. It could be many things:

**Possible Code Errors**

1. You misspelled a key name
2. Ensure that you actually set the values
3. Perhaps you are passing some variables via the URL www.example.com?var=x (GET) and then trying to reference `$_POST['var']` instead of `$_GET['var']`
4. Perhaps you did not actually POST to the page. If you are submitting from a form ensure the `method` attribute is set to `POST` (method="POST")

I'm sure there are many other possibilities (like your dev environment), but it is unlikely that `$_POST` is inconsistent. I would need to see more code on your end.

**Possible Environment/Usage Errors**

1. Ensure WAMP is started (It doesn't always auto start)
2. Ensure you are accessing your page via `http://localhost/path/file.php` and not trying to open it up straight from the folder it is in i.e. `C:\path\file.php`. It must run through Apache.

i.e. Is it only `$_POST` that is not working? if you type `<?php echo "TEST"; ?>` in your script, doest it echo out `TEST`?

Comment: I copied the working file, renamed it and trimmed some unnecessary lines. thats it. no compilation errors, but still its not working.

Comment: @luckyluke I added some suggestions. I want you to change the line `print($first_name);` to `print("name: $first_name);` does it print out anything? I'm taking a guess that `name:` isn't even going to print out.
`

Comment: Yess kenny its not even print any thing.

Comment: So are you 100% sure that WAMP is running. It seems that it isn't. And what happens when you try opening "http://localhost/path/file.php" in your Internet browser?

Comment: Note that most Apache installations, if you type `http://localhost/` in the browser it should say something like, "It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

Comment: when i view the localhost i'm able to see Server Configuration, tools, phpinfo(), phpmyadmin etc., however when i try accessing localhost/path/file.php it says "The requested URL /path/file.php was not found on this server."

Comment: replace "/path/file.php" with your actual file name. Your files should be placed in the  "c:\wamp\www\". so for example if you place `test.php` in `c:\wamp\www`, then access it via `http://localhost/test.php` in your browser, I bet it will work.

Comment: @luckyluke Let me know how my suggestions worked, and upvote if they were useful :)

Comment: its still blank. Thanks Guru. Thanks for your continued support with much patience for this beginner. but i'll try to make things work. Thanks again

Answer (score -3):

you have to check the name of field in HTML file ,which you are going to post.so,may be there is a problem in your field name in HTML file.look it carefully.